# Hasta que punto puedo modificar una clase serializable?

Tags: c#, serialización, binary-files

Supongamos que tengo un fichero binario donde voy guardando objetos de una clase "PERSONAS"...
Y el día de mañana creo conveniente modificar esta clase. Podria seguir leyendo el archivo previo? Podría seguir guardado esta clase con nuevas variables en el mismo fichero sin romperlo? Podria heredar las variables existentes y seguir funcionando? hasta que punto se puede modificar? Una gran duda que tengo...

Comment: nunca lo hice, pero te sacas la duda haciendo un archivo, y despues modifica la clase.

Comment: Hasta donde yo he podido ver, deberia ser posible mientras la nueva version de la clases sea compatible con la definicion actual (campos existentes siguen existiendo y nuevos atributos son opcionales o tienen valor por defecto inicializado)

Comment: Se puede aplicar el principio Open Closed, te recomiendo una lectura de eso, y luego de eso, podrías crear una clase principal abstracta, también podría ser una interface y usar esas abstracciones y no las concreciones (clase Persona) si no un IPersona o un AbstractPersona con los atributos necesarios para cada tipo.

Comment: Gracias jtaborga, le voy a pegar una leida